# NoMethodError: undefined method `onvos_encoded_url' -- ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I'm having some issues trying to call an instance:

in my first model file: "video.rb" a got this code :

```
class Vimeo::Video < ActiveRecord::Base
      def onvos_encoded_url
        hash = json_onvos()
        enc = Base64.encode64(hash.to_json)
        return URI::encode(enc)
      end
end
```

them I try to call it scheduller.rake

```
desc "Tareas"
task :update_videos => :environment do
    onvos_service()
end

def onvos_service
   @enc = Vimeo::Video.onvos_encoded_url
   puts @enc
end
```

i got the massage

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `onvos_encoded_url' for #<Class:0x007fe003e9eef0>

Tasks: TOP => update_videos
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined an instance method but you called it as a class method.

You have 2 options:

**Use a class method**

In your class:

```
class Vimeo::Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.onvos_encoded_url
    hash = json_onvos()
    enc = Base64.encode64(hash.to_json)
    return URI::encode(enc)
  end
end
```

In your rake task:

```
desc "Tareas"
task :update_videos => :environment do
    onvos_service()
end

def onvos_service
  @enc = Vimeo::Video.onvos_encoded_url
  puts @enc
end
```

**Use an instance method**

In your class:

```
class Vimeo::Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.onvos_encoded_url
    hash = json_onvos()
    enc = Base64.encode64(hash.to_json)
    return URI::encode(enc)
  end
end
```

In your rake task:

```
desc "Tareas"
task :update_videos => :environment do
    onvos_service()
end

def onvos_service
  @enc = Vimeo::Video.new.onvos_encoded_url
  puts @enc
end
```

As an unrelated aside, ruby implicitly returns the last expression in a method so the `return`s are not necessary in this context.

Comment: You told him the right thing, but you should adjust his code to make it clear.

Comment: thanks Josh, would you mind give me an example because I'm a little bit confuse how should I call it

Comment: @EdoardoLopez added examples

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def onvos_encoded_url
```

to

```
def self.onvos_encoded_url
```

Because you want to define a class method and not an instance method.